# Mocking imported class in another module

Tags: node.js, jasmine, mocking

Need to mock the method objBBB.GetResult() from spec file to handle the failure scenario. since it is imported in AAA module not able to access and mock the required results.

Also I'm always getting 'Success' result as my mock method was not called. Please do let me know it there are any work around for this problem.

```
// Service code
import BBB = require('../data_layer/BBB_dl');
const objBBB: BBB.BBBDL = new BBB.BBBDL();

export default class AAA{

 public async DoThings(event, callBack) {
    ....
    let res = objBBB.GetResult();
    if(res === 1){
      ...
     return 'Success'
    } else {
      ....
     return 'Failed'
    }
 }
}

// Unit test code
import AAA from '../data_layer/AAA_bl';
import BBB = require('../data_layer/BBB_dl');
const objBBB: BBB.BBBDL = new BBB.BBBDL();

const AAAObj: AAA = new AAA();

it('scenario 2 test', async function () {
    const expected: any = 'Failed';
    objBBB.GetResult = jasmine.createSpy('objBBB.GetResult() spy')
    .and.returnValue('Failed');
    result = await AAAObj.DoThings(event, tempCallback);
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the spy on your existing object `objBBB` using [spyOn](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/global.html#spyOn) instead of [createSpy](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.7/jasmine.html#.createSpy). The latter creates a bare `spy` object.

```
spyOn(objBBB, 'GetResult').and.returnValue('Failed');
```